# Using loops to check time between actions

Tags: python, function, loops, timeout, python-multithreading

I have two functions. What I want to do here is: when `ser.write('1')` (i.e. when Python is telling keep the gate open), I want to note the time and keep the door open for 8 seconds. Now, if within
that time, `send_data(data)` returns true, I want to write `ser.write('0')` or keep the gate closed.

Can anyone suggest me how to implement this? I tried to do this via a while loop, but I was not successful.

```
def send_data(data):
    if (data ==0):
        print "manga"
        return True
    else:
        print "muringa"
        return False

def delay_for_goodant(data):
    print "thenga"
    global ser
    try:
        if (ser == None):
            ser = serial.Serial("COM1",9600,timeout = 0)
        if send_data(data) is True:
            ser.write('0')
            print "python is telling arduino to keep the gate closed"
        else:
            start_time_opening = time.time()
            ser.write('1')
            end_time_opening = time.time()
            elapsed_time =  end_time_opening - start_time_opening
            print "time taken for opening is"+ str(end_time_opening - start_time_opening)
            if elapsed_time < 8 and send_data(data) is True:
                ser.write('0')
            elif elapsed_time < 8 and send_data(data) is False:
                ser.write('1')
            incoming_data2 = ser.readline()
            print "python is telling the arduino to keep the gate open"
            print "incoming_data for opening is-",(incoming_data2)
```

Comment: is this code compiled and written to an arduino board? If so, i don't think you can use all the normal python modules

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your description sorry. However, I _think_ your issue here might be related to function calls being blocking. "If in the meantime x happens" doesn't make sense because everything will stop until the function returns. You might need to look into threading. I could be wrong, are you able to clarify the expected flow in your question?

Comment: Yes, as @roganjosh says, you need Python's **threading** package.  You want two different logic control paths to operate at the same time; a separate control path is called a **thread**.  The package supplies communication and dependence primitives between threads.  Among other things, you can have one thread message or interrupts another.

Comment: @omu_negru yes, I am using the pyserial library.

Comment: @roganjosh. As Prune told, i have two different control to operate at the same time.

Comment: @Prune Can you provide an idea on how to implement this. I went through the documentation for threads. I was not able to get much insight.

Comment: @Hi i modified the code, but it doesnot seems to work

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  "it doesnot seems to work [sic]" is not a problem specification.

Comment: You may need an hour or so working through tutorials, or finding someone who knows threading already.  Stack Overflow is not a place for concept and implementation tutorials.